# How to limit concurrency with scheduled rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Following scenario:
I have a lambda (`L1`), which is triggered by several services (`s1, s2, ... sN`) via a scheduledRule(`r1 ,r2 , ... rN`) configured with cron.
The problem is that two Lambdas of type `L1` triggered by the same service via the same scheduledRule must never run simultaneously. So a lambda that was triggered by `s1` over `r1`, if it has not finished in the time until the next scheduled execution, may not be started again.
Two Lambdas that were triggered by different services via different rules should be allowed to run simultaneously.

The only possibility I can think of at the moment would be to put an `SQS` between rule and lambda.

Is there a more elegant solution or does `SQS` sound practical?

Comment: this "feels" like an anti-pattern. Lambda is meant to be stateless, so creating dependencies such as this go against the grain. orchestrating work, which the above sounds like, should leverage step functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamodb to store status info, if there is running process. It's extreamly fast. Just remember to enable strongly consistent reads